# Skybox doesn't show on RenderTexture

Tags: unity-game-engine

When broadcasting from a camera to a renderTexture, the skybox doesn't show on the renderTexture. I have tried to add a skybox component to the camera for it to use instead of the default skybox, didn't work. I have tried simply using the skybox's material as a material for an Image component and place it beneath the renderTexture, it shows the skybox correctly but also raises an error that the material doesn't have a "_MainTex" component ("Material doesn't have a texture property '_MainTex'"). What is the correct way of broadcasting a camera to a renderTexture including the skybox?

Comment: The skybox is included when drawing to a screen? What render pipeline do you use?

Comment: The skybox shows normally when drawing to the screen, the Scriptable Render Pipeline Settings is set to "None".